# How correctly to make a PUT request in my case?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am a beginner in Angular.
When I click on a button "Update", I want to send only one array object to the back-end. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, because my method does not send changes in the form. Can someone check my code? How correctly make PUT in this case?

categories.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {Category} from '../../../shared/models/category';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ProductsService} from '../../../shared/services/products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss']
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  // categories = [
  //   {id: 1, name: 'veloglasses', uaName: 'Велоокуляри'},
  //   {id: 2, name: 'skiglasses', uaName: 'Лижні окуляри'},
  //   {id: 3, name: 'frames', uaName: 'Оправи'},
  //   {id: 4, name: 'accesories', uaName: 'Аксесуари'}
  // ];
  categories: Category[];

  categoryForm: FormGroup;

  isEditable = true;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private productService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const categoryArray = this.fb.array([]);
    this.categoryForm = this.fb.group({
      categories: categoryArray
    });

    this.productService.getCategories().subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data;
      this.categories.forEach(category => {
        categoryArray.push(this.createCategoryGroup(category));
        console.log(category);
      });
    });
  }

  createCategoryGroup(category: any = {}) {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: this.fb.control(category.id),
      name: this.fb.control(category.name),
      uaName: this.fb.control(category.uaName)
    });
  }

  addCategory() {
    this.categoriesArray.push(this.createCategoryGroup());
  }

  onSubmit(i) {
    const category: Category = {
      id: this.categoriesArray.at(i).value.id,
      name: this.categoriesArray.at(i).value.name,
      uaName: this.categoriesArray.at(i).value.uaName
    };
    this.productService.updateCategory(category).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
    console.log(category);
    console.log(this.categoriesArray.at(i).value.name);
  }

  removeCategory(index) {
    this.categoriesArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  get categoriesArray() {
    return (this.categoryForm.get('categories') as FormArray);
  }

}
```

categories.component.html

```
<form id="productCategories" [formGroup]="categoryForm">
  <div class="form-group" formArrayName="categories">
    <div *ngFor="let category of categoriesArray.controls; let i = index;">
      <div class="row"  [formGroupName]="i">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" formControlName="id">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="uaName">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="removeCategory(i)">Remove</button>
        <button class="btn" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(i)">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="button" (click)="addCategory()">Add Category</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

products.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Product} from '../models/product';
import {Category} from '../models/category';

const header = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private categoriesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/products/categories';

  ...

  public getCategories() {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl);
  }

  public getCategory(category) {
    return this.http.get<Category>(this.categoriesUrl + '/' + category.id);
  }

  public createCategory(category: Category) {
    return this.http.post<Category>(this.categoriesUrl + '/add', category);
  }

  public updateCategory(category: Category) {
    return this.http.put<Category>(this.categoriesUrl + '/' + category.id + '/update', category);
  }

  public deleteCategory(category) {
    return this.http.delete(this.categoriesUrl + '/' + category.id);
  }



}
```

[My result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19F6cDI1wlHenHWmcKo3bPLAiQuTmUnqr)

Comment: Can you show us how your network looks like after you run `updateCategoty`?

Comment: @Akxe Yes [1] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=16-JisEiba47teokGbDK5RQqBv7QTlEEO) [2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YtFbeyixlDnlJH35t1kusArPnQFvKZGq) [3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gWXqPzu9qeLf4hP-CUWsH01eR-TYQV2s) [4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WwLKzNVO-wGqiCfYI2V0ZXsVFpU0YuON)

Comment: If you are using form builder you don’t need control methods just pass in objects to fb.group({id:cat.id})

Comment: @TarasSvidnytskyy I can see some values in every fields, what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you getting any CORS errors ?
   If yes, please configure proxy, link [here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/)

```
 {
  "/products/categories/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Just to clarify, now since you are getting 200 OK, it means :

a) HTTP status code 200 OK for a successful PUT of an update to an existing resource. **No response body needed**.

b) HTTP status code 201 Created for a successful PUT of a new resource, with the most specific URI for the new resource returned in the Location header field and any other relevant URIs and metadata of the resource echoed in the response body.

Since you are getting, 200 OK and its just an update, you need to check in server if the response has been updated or not, no need to manipulate UI.

Comment: I have no CORS Errors

Comment: Can you share, your network tab results :
1) HttpStatus : 201 etc?
2) Preview of response you got
3) Content-Type which server is expecting

Comment: Yes, of course: [1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WwLKzNVO-wGqiCfYI2V0ZXsVFpU0YuON)[2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gWXqPzu9qeLf4hP-CUWsH01eR-TYQV2s) [3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YtFbeyixlDnlJH35t1kusArPnQFvKZGq) [4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16-JisEiba47teokGbDK5RQqBv7QTlEEO)

Comment: preview is pending

Comment: @TarasSvidnytskyy Have edited my response, please check

Comment: Ignore response from OPTIONS call, 2nd request is actual PUT request, why OPTIONS? : check [Preflight-Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) , and for update via put, you will not get any response as mentioned in my answer, you will only get 200 OK.